# How "ignore" value in Notepad++ find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help.
One time I did it but I'm not remembering how to do it.
I'll try to explain.

I want replace in Notepad++ lines like this:

> "Has **1%** chance to do something";

I want change this line but I need ignore this % value, because other lines like this has others values.

Comment: Do you mean you want an output of `"Has chance to do something"? If not, can you clarify?

Comment: I need just know how can I ignore the % value.
I don't know how to explain better. :(

Because others lines has same text, only the value is different, so I want to use Find and Replace function to edit all this lines, but I need ignore the "%" value to do it.

I've did it one time using regex, but I don't remember, I tried yesterday but without sucess. Sorry I'm newbie

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said, I need change this text, and ignore only the % value. Because others lines has same text and only the value is different, so I want to use Find and Replace function to edit all this lines, but need to ignore the "%" and change only the text in all lines. Sorry I really don't know how to explain better, I'm newbie.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Please give examples (in an edit to your question, so your question is clear)

Comment: Please provide an example so that I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to use the number in your replace value, if you have the text:

```
"Has 1% chance to do something";
"Has 15% chance to do something";
"Has 25% chance to do something";
"Has 44% chance to do something";
```

use in **find** the next regex:

```
(Has )([0-9]+% )(chance to do something)
```

And in the replace value something like:

```
percent $2 is mainteined
```

The **$2** indicate to use in the replace value the second group of the regex finded. The result is:

```
"percent 1%  is mainteined";
"percent 15%  is mainteined";
"percent 25%  is mainteined";
"percent 44%  is mainteined";
```

The groups in the regex are noted for the values between **"()"**. The first group is the **1**.